Footable: How to render same hidden columns multiple times within a single row
I am using row expand feature of footable to show hidden columns within a row (on click).
What I have/Issue:

I have same column description which is repeating 4 times (as it has 4 services associated with it).
Picture(Rows Expanded):



As you can see, quantity is 4 on right side which is the quantity of these services associated with single row description.

What I want:

I want to render these combo of (service and availed date) to render within single row only.
Example:

X                                      |   4   |   0
Service a
Availed Date
Service b
Availed Date
Service c
Availed Date
Service d
Availed Date
What changes should I make to reflect these changes?
